# How to find Position of a child element(number) inside a parent in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table inside that there are several rows and in each row there is a select control.

On changing the change event of the `Select control` I need to add a row below that.

But the row should add only if the `Select control` is in the last row.

How to find the position of the row(like 3rd row) in which the selectcontrol is present
I can't post an image of that any way my source is like this:

```
<tbody id="tbdConditionalSearch">
                                <tr id="trSearchRow">
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" value=""/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="selectOperator" onchange="AddConditionalSearchRow(this)">
                                            <option value="-1" selected>Select</option>
                                            <option value="0">AND</option>
                                            <option value="1">OR</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               <tr id="trSearchRow">
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" value=""/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="selectOperator" onchange="AddConditionalSearchRow(this)">
                                                <option value="-1" selected>Select</option>
                                                <option value="0">AND</option>
                                                <option value="1">OR</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

**I want to add more rows below this row.**

Currently new rows are adding even if I select on the Select control in the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JS:

```
function AddConditionalSearchRow(sel) {
    var row = sel.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (row.rowIndex === row.parentNode.rows.length-1) {
        // add a new row
    }
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/c9XYS/

jQuery:

```
function AddConditionalSearchRow(sel) {
    if ($(sel).closest("tr").is(":last-child")) {
        // add a new row
    }
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/c9XYS/1/

Comment: var rowNumber = $(objSelect).parent().parent()[0].rowIndex;

Answer (score 2):

I think the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method may be what you're looking for...

Comment: I dont know how to explain that. It is wrong to say that biut I wnat to find "How manyth" row my select control is situated

Comment: Actually `index` is what *I* was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should use jQuery to add your event handlers. I added the class of `operator` to each select in your example to do this. Secondly, you can use the `:last-child` selector on the closest `tr` element to find out if it is the last in the table. Try this:

```
$('.operator').change(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
        alert('last');
        //AddConditionalSearchRow(this);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/CgaXP/)

Comment: Why change your answer?

Comment: This is what I originally had but I changed it thinking it didn't work, but that was due to a missing bracket in the if condition, so I changed it back.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a new row when the last select as a value != -1.

```
function AddConditionalSearchRow() {
    var lastSelectValue = $('#tbdConditionalSearch select:last').val();
    if (lastSelectValue != -1) {
        // add your new row here
    }
}
```

Btw, you have two ids with same name (id="trSearchRow"), use classes, ids are unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).parent().parent().index() == $('#tbdConditionalSearch > tr').length - 1) {

}
```

By the way, it is not a good idea to put the same ID on all your rows. Use a class instead.